# php export mysql table to excel and create a local file, not download

Tags: php, export-to-excel

I have this code that is working well, it creates the Excel file and sends me to download through browser.

How can I adapt this code to, not to download, but create the same file in local directory?

```
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($con->connect_error) {  //error check
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}
else
{

}


$DB_TBLName = "tblenc"; 
$filename = "excelfilename";  //your_file_name
$file_ending = "xls";   //file_extention

header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.'.'.$file_ending");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");

$sep = "\t";

$sql="SELECT * FROM $DB_TBLName"; 
$resultt = $con->query($sql);
while ($property = mysqli_fetch_field($resultt)) { //fetch table field name
    echo $property->name."\t";
}

print("\n");    

while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($resultt))  //fetch_table_data
{
    $schema_insert = "";
    for($j=0; $j< mysqli_num_fields($resultt);$j++)
    {
        if(!isset($row[$j]))
            $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
        elseif ($row[$j] != "")
            $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
        else
            $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
    }
    $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert .= "\t";
    print(trim($schema_insert));
    print "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: change print to `file_put_contents()` When in doubt, [Read Through The PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) Or [open a file and write to it](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) **The manual should be your first port of call not SO**

Answer (score 0):

Remove the headers at the top of the file and instead of printing each line, store it into a file.

If the file is rather small, then you can use `file_put_contents()` like so:

```
$sep = "\t";

$output = '';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $DB_TBLName";
$resultt = $con->query($sql);
while ($property = mysqli_fetch_field($resultt)) { //fetch table field name
    $output .= $property->name."\t";
}

$output .= "\n";

foreach ($resultt as $row) {  //fetch_table_data
    $schema_insert = "";
    foreach ($row as $field) {
        if (!isset($field)) {
            $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
        } elseif ($field != "") {
            $schema_insert .= $field.$sep;
        } else {
            $schema_insert .= $sep;
        }
    }
    $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert .= "\t";
    // append a new line to our file output
    $output .= trim($schema_insert)."\n";
}
```

If you have a large file then you should use `fopen()` instead. Instead of concatenating the whole output, you can save each line on its own straight into a file using `fwrite()` and save memory usage.

```
$fp = fopen('data.csv', 'w');

$output = '';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $DB_TBLName";
$resultt = $con->query($sql);
while ($property = mysqli_fetch_field($resultt)) { //fetch table field name
    $output .= $property->name."\t";
}

$output .= "\n";
fwrite($fp, $output);

foreach ($resultt as $row) {  //fetch_table_data
    $schema_insert = "";
    foreach ($row as $field) {
        if (!isset($field)) {
            $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
        } elseif ($field != "") {
            $schema_insert .= $field.$sep;
        } else {
            $schema_insert .= $sep;
        }
    }
    $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert .= "\t";
    // append a new line to our file output
    fwrite($fp, trim($schema_insert)."\n");
}

// close file pointer
fclose($fp);
```